# UK Sonic Art / Electronic Music Festivals

Tags: sound-art, music, uk

*Sorry if this is a little off topic...*

**Does anyone in the UK know of or attend any Sonic Art and/or Electronic music festivals?
 I've heard of a few myself but am looking to experience more.**

I know it's slightly off topic, however for me personally I always find sonic art and electronic music (*leaning more towards IDM, Glitch etc.*) greatly influences and inspires my sound design - This is particularly the case with my latest project utilising a merger of the two and sound design, which compliment the piece well.

I thought it would be of interest to a number of people so I'll update this post as I find more festivals/performances etc. It would be cool to hear about live laptop ensembles as well. Also, I don't know if people would prefer for it to be a community wiki page? Just let me know and I'll change it :)

I've asked a related question before if you're interested: [Music Makers: Do you find your Sound Design skills influence your compositions?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/9328/music-makers-do-you-find-your-sound-design-skills-influence-your-compositions)

**LIST OF UK FESTIVALS:** - *in progress*

Sound Art / Experimental Electronic Music  - http://www.audiograft.com/
Experimental Electronic Music / Workshops / Installations - http://www.beamfestival.com/
Sonic Art / Experimental Electronic Music / Lectures / Installations - http://noisefloor.co.uk
Electronic Music  - http://www.blocweekend.com/

Comment: man, been desperate to find something like this. also as a music producer. thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Two off the top of my head: Beam Festival, at Brunel University (http://www.beamfestival.com/), and AudioGraft, in Oxford (http://www.audiograft.com/). I used to know someone who ran an electronica/sound-art festival called 'Sonic boom' in Coventry, but I don't think that's still going on.